# Calling class file of another application

Tags: java, javascript, class, jsp

I have a JSP on my application1. I want to call a class file from another application2 to perform insert operations on click of button in application1.

Can someone please give me an idea how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two options as far as I am aware.

1) Make the class you want to call from application2 available to application1 and then call it.

2) Expose the functionality of the class as a web service in application2, and then use it from application1

Answer (score 0):

Make an object of that class(assuming class is accessible) and call that method(assuming method is accessible)